# C# word finder error

Tags: c#, arrays, console-application

I've made a program to find a specific word in a user-inputted sentence. I did this in C# console application. Here's the whole code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Word_finder_control_assessment_test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' };
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a sentence ");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            string text = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine().ToLower());


            string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars);

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter the word to find");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            string wordtofind = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine().ToLower());


            for (int position = 0; position < text.Length; position++)
            {

                string tempword = words[position]; // at the end of this application this is highlighted yellow and an error returns : Index was outside the bounds of the array. My application works perfectly except for that.
                if (wordtofind == tempword)
                {



                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine("The position of the word is {0} ", position + 1);
                    Console.ReadLine();

                }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I've commented the problem I had in the code.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're using `text.Length` and not `words.Length`, you're looking at the length of the entire sentence, not the number of elements within the array.

You're best bet is to do a foreach over the array, as you would have been able to really see what the for loop is doing.

```
foreach(string tempWord in words)
{
    // put code here
}
```

Be sure you're looking closely at these sorts of problems, and utilize verbose and friendly names so it's obvious what you're looping over.

Comment: could you demonstrate that in my code please? I don't quite understand

Comment: For simplicity if you're looking at your code you need to change 

`for (int position = 0; position < text.Length; position++)`
to
`for (int position = 0; position < words.Length; position++)`

Comment: To further Explain. if you're user input "This is my sentence", `text.Length` would equal 19, but `words.Length` would equal 4, which is what you want to be looking at as you're using the `position` as an index of `words`, not `text`

Comment: Not a problem, Just be sure you understand why is wasn't working, as it seems this is probably a school project, and as a new programmer you should make sure you fully understand these runtime errors, it's easy to overlook something like that, or use a wrong sign in an if statement. use comments to help and as mentioned before, useful naming conventions, if `text` was instead `userInput` it would have been easily seen that you shoudn't be looking at `userInput`, but instead the words array